# Why does mhchem complain about this?

Tags: mhchem

Alright, I'm trying to make a command to insert a proton. This code works fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\newcommand{\tphoton}{$\gamma$}

\begin{document}
\tphoton
\end{document}
```

and this code works fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\ce{$\gamma$}
\end{document}
```

Why doesn't this code work?

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\newcommand{\tphoton}{$\gamma$}

\begin{document}
\ce{\tphoton}
\end{document}
```

It gives a "! Missing $ inserted.", 3 "! Extra }, or forgotten $."

Comment: `\tphoton` or `\tproton`, you decide. But example 1 throws an error right now, too. ;-)

Comment: @lockstep Fixed: I pasted an old testcase in by accident.I switched to \tphoton since it was more minimal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The argument of mhchem's `\ce` already is a "hidden math mode". `\ce{\bfseries B}` will give

> ! LaTeX Error: Command \bfseries invalid in math
>   mode.

Try `\ensuremath` instead:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\newcommand{\tphoton}{\ensuremath{\gamma}}

\begin{document}
\ce{\tphoton}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why does `\ce{$\gamma$}` work then? (my guess is that it becomes `...$$\gamma$$...`, which is also valid).

Comment: I guess that the `\ce` gobbles the `$`. `\ce{$\gamma$}`, `\ce{$$\gamma$$}` and even `\ce{$$$\gamma$$$}` work fine.