# Typesetting transition metal cluster in mhchem?

Tags: mhchem

I would like to use `mhchem`'s `\ce` command to typeset a transition metal cluster.  If I use `\ce{[Ru(cod)($2\text{-}$methylallyl)2]}`, I get the correct output, but it is very much a hack.  I have tried to use `\ce{[Ru(cod)(2-methylallyl)2]}` but this incorrectly sets the first `2` as a subscript.  What is the correct way to handle this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}
  Compare \ce{[Ru(cod)($2\text{-}$methylallyl)2]} with \ce{[Ru(cod)(2-methylallyl)2]}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good question! `mhchem`'s manual doesn't mention escaping from its formula parsing which not only sets the `2` as subscript but also transforms the dash (`-`) into a single bond.

It does mention one way implicitly: using `$...$`. Thus the usual way to prevent `mhchem`'s parsing is indeed to switch to math mode, *i.e.*, use `$...$` inside `\ce{}`. So your hack is not so much a hack, really, but for many cases the way to go. It is unfortunate, though, to escape to math mode just to go back to text mode with `\text{}` again. In cases like yours an `\mbox{}` is probably better or at least easier and less to type:

```
\ce{[Ru(cod)(\mbox{2-}methylallyl)2]}
```

Another way would be to omit the `$...$` and to use `\text{}` directly: `mhchem`'s formulas all are already in math mode! The documentation doesn't advertise this ([which sometimes causes unexpected errors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41187/5049)).

```
\ce{[Ru(cod)(\text{2-methylallyl})2]}
```

There is actually another implicit way to prevent a number being set as a subscript: make `mhchem` believe that it is a stoichiometric factor by leaving a blank before the number:

```
\ce{[Ru(cod)( 2-methylallyl)2]}
```

This, however, will lead to an unwanted space *after* the dash! This is the space that `mhchem` inserts after stoichiometric factors which can be verified by setting `\mhchemoptions{skip-after-amount=}`. Since `-` is not a letter (i.e. it hasn't catcode 11) it is interpreted as part of the stoichiometric factor.

A comparison of the different cases:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
 \verb!\ce{[Ru(cod)(2-methylallyl)2]}! & \ce{[Ru(cod)(2-methylallyl)2]} \\
 \verb!\ce{[Ru(cod)($2\text{-}$methylallyl)2]}! & \ce{[Ru(cod)($2\text{-}$methylallyl)2]} \\
 \verb!\ce{[Ru(cod)( 2-methylallyl)2]}! & \ce{[Ru(cod)( 2-methylallyl)2]} \\
 \verb!\mhchemoptions{skip-after-amount=}!: \\
 \verb!\ce{[Ru(cod)( 2-methylallyl)2]}! & \mhchemoptions{skip-after-amount=}\ce{[Ru(cod)( 2-methylallyl)2]} \\
 \verb!\catcode`\-=11!: \\
 \verb!\ce{[Ru(cod)( 2-methylallyl)2]}! & \catcode`\-=11 \ce{[Ru(cod)( 2-methylallyl)2]} \\
 \verb!\ce{[Ru(cod)(\mbox{2-}methylallyl)2]}! & \ce{[Ru(cod)(\mbox{2-}methylallyl)2]} \\
 \verb!\ce{[Ru(cod)(\text{2-methylallyl})2]}! & \ce{[Ru(cod)(\text{2-methylallyl})2]}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

#### Edit 2017/05/30

The problem doesn't show with the current version of `mhchem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\verb!\ce{[Ru(cod)(2-methylallyl)2]}! \ce{[Ru(cod)(2-methylallyl)2]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For comparison: with [`chemmacros`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) you would write `\ch{[Ru(cod)( "2-methylallyl" )2]}`

Answer (score 4):

With mhchem v4.00, you can write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
  \ce{[Ru(cod)(2-methylallyl)2]}
\end{document}
```

[image]